# Use custom get results query to show posts WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code before to show posts.

```
$query_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => 4,
                'meta_key' => 'Views',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
if( $the_query->have_posts() )
{
    while( $the_query->have_posts() )
    {
        $the_query->the_post();                 
        echo    '<a class="popularPostLinks" href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" rel="external" target="_blank">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '
                        <br>
                        <div>
                            <p>' . get_the_title() . '</p>
                        </div>
                </a>';
    }
}
else
{
    // No posts found.
}
// Restore original post data.
wp_reset_postdata();
```

but now i am using my custom query:

```
$getAllTimeRows = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id, SUM( post_value ) AS 'Views' FROM {$wpdb->prefix}PopularPosts GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY Views DESC LIMIT 4" ) );
```

How can i used this above array result to show posts same like how WP Query is showing the posts? The `$getAllTimeRows` contains rows (max 4) to show (max 4) posts. See below the array.

```
print_r ( $getAllTimeRows  )

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 213
            [Views] => 16
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 215
            [Views] => 11
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 217
            [Views] => 9
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 227
            [Views] => 7
        )

)
```

Comment: You would modify the SQL query to join the wp_posts table and fetch the id on post_id. Who created that SQL query for you?

Comment: i created it by myself. i am storing the post id in my custom table

Comment: when the user see a single post i stored its id in the custom table.

Comment: but i don't get it how to show these post id posts.

Comment: `FROM {$wpdb->prefix}PopularPosts as P left join wp_posts as W on P.post_id = W.id` or some variation of this...The jist ist hat you need the JOIN statement.

Comment: but why i need this query? i already have the posts post_id which i want to show. i just want to show there permalink and title

Comment: Then use a foreach statement and `get_the_ID($std->post_ID)` and `get_the_title($std->post_ID)`

Comment: thats a nice tip. I haven't thought about this. thanks alot i will figure it out (y)

Comment: I would not recommend it for large loops as each of those functions natively calls a SQL query if the data wasn't populated in $wpdb.

Comment: then what should i do?